# Cannot find RSS Viewer WebPart in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, web-part, rss

All,

I am new to Sharepoint development. We have a sharepoint 2013 server. I have a RSS link and I want to view it on a simple page. The basic idea would be to find the RSS Webpart, Add it to the page and configure it to consume the feed link. From my research I was able to figure out that the RSS Webpart was moved from the "Media and Content" category in 2010 to "Content Rollup" category in 2013. But I was unable to find a RSS Webpart under any category .

Is there some setting or feature that needs to be enabled on the server to view the web part ? Or should I be able to download it and upload it myself? I was unable to find any leads and all I could get was third party paid webparts for RSS. I was reluctant to pay when it is already being provided with sharepoint. Any help is highly appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: I'm new to SP, too. I'm using 2013.  I see the RSS Viewer directly under Content Rollup.  I don't know of your setup, but I had enabled publishing, because I had to implement a custom design.  I have no idea if that is why I see it.

Comment: @CMKanode: I also have the Publishing Feature Enabled, but still do not find the RSS Viewer Webpart

Comment: Well, poop.  I wonder what's different?  I've got a test site that is enterprise and a live site that is standard.  Both have that part available.  Are you using Foundation?  It may not be available in that based on a cursory web search.

Comment: @CMKanode I have standard. So, I should have the web part. I am guessing its something with activating some sort of setting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to "Site Collection Features" and then Activate "SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection features" this will Activate Most of the Web parts you need.